# How can I align bones position with mesh when using shapekeys?

Tags: armature, shape-keys

I have mesh that bends to left with shapekey and I also have an armature attached to the mesh. I need that armature to somehow follow the mesh position, it this possible to do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: is your mesh parented to the bones? If so, it will make the mesh bend even more and the bones won't be able to follow... if not, you could do it with hooks I guess

Comment: Yes, it is parented to bones.

Comment: so what you want doesn't make sens in my opinion but maybe you should tell a bit more

Comment: I need some sort of solution, maybe with drivers to move bones like they move in edit mode, so mesh wont be affected by changed bones position

Comment: please explain your project more in detail

Comment: I am trying to animate this green object with shapekeys but when I rotate "basis" shapekey it screws all other shapekeys. I thought that shapekey animation maintain movement of vertices of the mesh no matter how this mesh is rotated or scaled. But it seems I was wrong so I am trying to animate that green object with both shapekeys and bones using bones to rotate object.

Comment: why don't you use bones for what you're trying to do, what limits have you encountered with bones?

Comment: I need to move certain vertices of mesh in certain place and bone doesn't have same level of precision as shapekeys where you can directly edit mesh. I know I can make a lot of bones to transform these certain vertices but shapekey seems to be faster to me

Comment: ok but for the movement you show on your screenshot, bones animations would be logical